# S5-model in which ◊X → □X is false?

Tags: logic

does someone know an example of this kind?

example of a S5-model in which ◊X → □X is false ?

And maybe if you can help me with these 2:

- Prove in K   ◊(A ∨ B) → □(◊A ∨ ◊B)
- Prove in T   □X → X